# Get cookie from Twig template

Tags: symfony, cookies, twig, drupal-8

I'm trying to access cookies I set in my Drupal website.
I created two cookies on a form submission :

- with the Drupal funtion = `user_cookie_save(['myfirstcookie' => 'myfirstdata'])`
- with the classic PHP function = `setcookie('mysecondcookie', 'myseconddata', time() + (86400 * 30), "/")`

My cookies are set, no problem.
But, I didn't find how to get them (or one of them) from my Twig templates. The app.request.cookies of Symfony seems to not exist.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Just pass the `$_COOKIE` variable from the controller to the view trough `twig`?

Comment: Not necessary but also highly discouraged to tangle with `$_COOKIE`.

Answer (score 61):

`Twig` has the global `app` helper context, via which you can access the cookies (among other things). Try this:

```
{{ dump(app.request.cookies) }}
```

And ultimately:

```
{{ app.request.cookies.get('MY_COOKIE_NAME') }}
```

Remember, `cookies` is an instance of `ParameterBag` ([API](http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ParameterBag.html)), so you have to access it via `get()` call.

Hope this helps...

Comment: This doesn't work in Drupal. Which is what OP asked for.

Comment: Twig does not have this global variable, that's something setup in whatever environment you are in.

Answer (score 0):

Past Cookie variable from the controller and check it. It works to me.
My code in controller is:

```
$data['cookie'] = $_COOKIE['postcode'];
```

postcode is my cookie name and in my twig templete, i write this line of code

```
{{  cookie  }}
```

and show my cookie value. Thanks.